# Solving an "wireless tools not found" error from airmon-ng tool

Tags: macos, mac, wifi

I am trying to use airmon-ng on Lion, but getting this error msg.

```
$ sudo !!
sudo airmon-ng 
Wireless tools not found
```

I installed aircrack with ports. I heard it is possible to use it with lion, but cannot find a solution for the "Wireless tools not found" problem.

Also, used KisMac as an alternative, but it seems to hang after fetching some packets (~50000).

Comment: It seems airmon-ng doesn't work on OSX, you need to use another monitoring tool.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, airmon-ng is not working on OS X, you will probably have to use a virtual PC with a linux OS + USB WiFi dongle. From [FAQ](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=faq#is_mac_os_x_supported):

### Is Mac OS X supported?

The aircrack-ng suite has limited Mac OS X support. Currently it only supports the following tools: aircrack-ng, packetforge-ng, ivstools and makeivs. Any program which requires opening a wireless interface is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

I traced it with `dtruss` and it is looking for the `iwpriv` command which is part of wireless-tools package on Linux systems (commands like `iwconfig`, `iwlist`, etc)

Output from a Ubuntu server box

```
mike@jarvis:~$ aptitude show wireless-tools
Package: wireless-tools
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 30~pre9-3ubuntu4
Priority: optional
Section: net
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Uncompressed Size: 463k
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libiw30 (>= 30~pre1)
Description: Tools for manipulating Linux Wireless Extensions
 This package contains the Wireless tools, used to manipulate the Linux Wireless Extensions. The Wireless Extension is an interface allowing you to set Wireless LAN specific parameters and get the specific stats.
Homepage: http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to come off like a smartypants but why don't you just do your capturing from a linux VM or Backtrack VM?  It's much more stable.  If you're just trying to capture packets use Wireshark (runs in x11) or Apple's built in Wi-Fi diagnostics in Core Services.  If you're trying to hack your own network, and you really want airmong-ng on Lion, you need Command Line Tools for Xcode, which you get from Apple's dev page.

Comment: trying to hack my own network, to see if it is really possible. I heard that running from a VM like VirtualBox it will not correctly work because there VM will not be able to set the wifi in monitor mode. Is that correct? I will give it a try anyway.

Comment: I've never had a problem but sometimes there are supported aircard issues that may prevent you from capturing with certain setups.  Unlike OS X, sometimes *nix distros take some tweaking, too.  What kind of Wireless Security Protocol are you trying to hack?

Comment: That being said, if you download the newest Xcode airmon-ng should work with Lion, although I haven't done it in awhile.

Comment: What do you mean Xcode airmon-ng? I searched for it on apple developer's website - could not find it.

Comment: Sorry.  Bad grammar.  It should say, if you download the newest Xcode, airmon-ng should work.  Try downloading Xcode and make sure you get the Command Line Tools package, as well.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the Command Line Tools component for Xcode.
To install this go to Xcode Preferences and in the Downloads tab select Command Line Tools and hit Download to the right, it's about 600MB.

Having said that, I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.2 and I also get "Wireless tools not found" when I try run airmon-ng.

Comment: airmon-ng is not part of the Command Line Tools, how should installing them help here?

Answer (score 0):

install the package wireless tools
it worked for me :)

Comment: Can you please share some details like where to get the package from, how to install and how to configure it? Details will make your answer much more valuable for other users here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
sudo wash -i en1
```

to scan wifi networks on macos